# Mongo Aggregate query - combine two AND queries

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework, querying

I have following collection in my database

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5bdba3101efdd9172de0b52f"),
    "year" : "2018",
    "identifier" : "2Z00CInO",
    "firstid" : "markt1995",
    "secondid" : "ninee87"
},
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5bdba3101efdd9172de0b52f"),
    "year" : "2018",
    "identifier" : "fl981nhg",
    "firstid" : "violentee9",
    "secondid" : "markt1995"
},
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5bdba3101efdd9172de0b52f"),
    "year" : "2018",
    "identifier" : "birk8mn",
    "firstid" : "eve1992",
    "secondid" : "toms78"
},
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5bdba3101efdd9172de0b52f"),
    "year" : "2015",
    "identifier" : "09man1l",
    "firstid" : "markt1995",
    "secondid" : "eve1992"
},
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5bdba3101efdd9172de0b52f"),
    "year" : "2017",
    "identifier" : "8h06KnO",
    "firstid" : "markt1995",
    "secondid" : "zepp988"
}
```

My desired output is:

1. All documents where 'firstid' and 'secondid' field is one of ids of document AND 'year' field is greater or equal 2018
2. AND 'firstid' + 'secondid' are both at once in document AND 'year' field is greater or equal 2015

I have $match stages which are selecting 1. and 2. properly but I can't combine them to get it in one output.

There are my values for variables from query, I'm using nodejs:

var firstid = markt1995

var secondid = eve1992

There is $match query to retrieve documents from first critera

```
$match: {
            $and: [{
              $or: [{
                  'firstid': {
                    "$in": [firstid, secondid]
                  }
                },
                {
                  'secondid': {
                    "$in": [firstid, secondid]
                  }
                }
              ],
              $and: [{
                'year': {
                  $gte: 2018
                }
              }],
            }]
    }
```

output:

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5bdba3101efdd9172de0b52f"),
    "year" : "2018",
    "identifier" : "2Z00CInO",
    "firstid" : "markt1995",
    "secondid" : "ninee87"
},
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5bdba3101efdd9172de0b52f"),
    "year" : "2018",
    "identifier" : "fl981nhg",
    "firstid" : "violentee9",
    "secondid" : "markt1995"
},
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5bdba3101efdd9172de0b52f"),
    "year" : "2018",
    "identifier" : "birk8mn",
    "firstid" : "eve1992",
    "secondid" : "toms78"
}
```

There is $match query to retrieve documents from second critera

```
$and: [{
              $or: [{
                'firstid': {
                  "$in": [firstid, secondid]
                },
                'secondid': {
                  "$in": [firstid, secondid]
                }
              }],
              $and: [{
                'year': {
                  $gte: 2015
                }
              }]

          }]
```

output:

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5bdba3101efdd9172de0b52f"),
    "year" : "2015",
    "identifier" : "09man1l",
    "firstid" : "markt1995",
    "secondid" : "eve1992"
}
```

Desired output in one query:

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5bdba3101efdd9172de0b52f"),
    "year" : "2018",
    "identifier" : "2Z00CInO",
    "firstid" : "markt1995",
    "secondid" : "ninee87"
},
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5bdba3101efdd9172de0b52f"),
    "year" : "2018",
    "identifier" : "fl981nhg",
    "firstid" : "violentee9",
    "secondid" : "markt1995"
},
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5bdba3101efdd9172de0b52f"),
    "year" : "2018",
    "identifier" : "birk8mn",
    "firstid" : "eve1992",
    "secondid" : "toms78"
},
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5bdba3101efdd9172de0b52f"),
    "year" : "2015",
    "identifier" : "09man1l",
    "firstid" : "markt1995",
    "secondid" : "eve1992"
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why don't you combine two conditions?

```
var firstid = 'markt1995';
var secondid = 'eve1992';
var a = [firstid,secondid ]
var c1 = {year:{$gte:2018},$or:[{firstid:{$in:a}},{secondid:{$in:a}}]};
var c2 = {year:{$gte:2015},firstid:{$in:a},secondid:{$in:a}};
db.getCollection('stack1').find(
    {$or:[c1,c2]}
)
```

Answer

```
/* 1 */
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5c078dd0410f22947d29dddc"),
    "year" : 2018,
    "identifier" : "2Z00CInO",
    "firstid" : "markt1995",
    "secondid" : "ninee87"
}

/* 2 */
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5c078dd0410f22947d29dddd"),
    "year" : 2018.0,
    "identifier" : "fl981nhg",
    "firstid" : "violentee9",
    "secondid" : "markt1995"
}

/* 3 */
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5c078dd0410f22947d29ddde"),
    "year" : 2018.0,
    "identifier" : "birk8mn",
    "firstid" : "eve1992",
    "secondid" : "toms78"
}

/* 4 */
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5c078dd0410f22947d29dddf"),
    "year" : 2015,
    "identifier" : "09man1l",
    "firstid" : "markt1995",
    "secondid" : "eve1992"
}
```